# Migrate from DateTimeField to DateField

Tags: python, django, migration

I have a model that contains a `created_at` field that is a `models.DateTimeField`. I want to migrate it to a `models.DateField` as the time is no longer necessary to have.  I change the mode, ran `makemigrations`, and applied it to my database. I foolishly assumed that the data would be migrated. No so, as all the `created_at` fields are now `None`.

How can I convert the existing data so the date is still available?

Here is the migration file that is generated:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
# Generated by Django 1.10.5 on 2017-03-01 15:07
from __future__ import unicode_literals

import datetime
from django.db import migrations, models


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        ('aion', '0003_auto_20160125_0948'),
    ]

    operations = [
        migrations.AlterField(
            model_name='assembly',
            name='created_at',
            field=models.DateField(default=datetime.date.today, verbose_name='date created'),
        ),
    ]
```

The database is a test one running on SQLite. The real one runs on MySQL…

```
$ python manage.py sqlmigrate aion 0004_auto_20170301_1507
BEGIN;
--
-- Alter field created_at on assembly
--
ALTER TABLE "aion_assembly" RENAME TO "aion_assembly__old";
CREATE TABLE "aion_assembly" ("created_at" date NOT NULL, "description" text NOT NULL, "serial_number" integer NOT NULL PRIMARY KEY AUTOINCREMENT, "status" varchar(32) NOT NULL, "manufacturer_serial_number" varchar(128) NULL, "supplier_reference" varchar(128) NULL, "sap" varchar(128) NULL, "location_number_field" varchar(128) NULL, "customer_equipment_reference" varchar(128) NULL, "configurator_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "aion_configurator" ("id"), "created_by_id" integer NOT NULL REFERENCES "auth_user" ("id"), "customer_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "organisations_customer" ("id"), "locality_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "aion_location" ("id"), "project_code_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "project_codes_projectcode" ("id"), "supplier_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "organisations_supplier" ("id"), "contained_in_id" integer NULL REFERENCES "aion_assembly" ("serial_number"));
INSERT INTO "aion_assembly" ("status", "customer_equipment_reference", "manufacturer_serial_number", "description", "supplier_reference", "created_at", "created_by_id", "project_code_id", "contained_in_id", "locality_id", "supplier_id", "location_number_field", "customer_id", "serial_number", "configurator_id", "sap") SELECT "status", "customer_equipment_reference", "manufacturer_serial_number", "description", "supplier_reference", "created_at", "created_by_id", "project_code_id", "contained_in_id", "locality_id", "supplier_id", "location_number_field", "customer_id", "serial_number", "configurator_id", "sap" FROM "aion_assembly__old";
DROP TABLE "aion_assembly__old";
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_cc6edc4a" ON "aion_assembly" ("configurator_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_e93cb7eb" ON "aion_assembly" ("created_by_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_cb24373b" ON "aion_assembly" ("customer_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_7e3ea948" ON "aion_assembly" ("locality_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_f56bb38b" ON "aion_assembly" ("project_code_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_c5bcd634" ON "aion_assembly" ("supplier_id");
CREATE INDEX "aion_assembly_e71ddfe4" ON "aion_assembly" ("contained_in_id");
COMMIT;
```

Comment: "No so, as all the created_at fields are now `None`." This surprises me. What database are you using? Can you [edit] your question and add the migration file?

Comment: And what database engine?

Comment: SQLite is wonderful, but it handles some things very differently from other database engines. In general it is a good idea to match your development environment as closely as possible to your production environment. This includes the database engine. (a) Please run [`manage.py sqlmigrate <app_label> <migration_name>`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/ref/django-admin/#django-admin-sqlmigrate) and add the result above. (This will show you the SQL that Django generates for your migration.) (b) If possible, please try the migration out on a MySQL database. I suspect it will work there.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SQLite is amazing, but it doesn't always behave the same way as other databases. Possibly relevant facts about SQLite include:

- [SQLite column types are somewhat dynamic](https://www.sqlite.org/datatype3.html)
- [SQLite's `ALTER TABLE` doesn't support column modification](https://www.sqlite.org/lang_altertable.html)

As you have seen, when working with SQLite Django actually creates a new table and copies data from the old one when you modify columns.

I'm not exactly sure where SQLite breaks in your situation, but since you are using MySQL in production I recommend using MySQL in development too. We have seen that this migration works as expected under MySQL.